# how to convert a date string into a NSDate type swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am attempting to take a string in the format *dd/mm/yyyy* and convert it to an NSDate so I can store a birthday. The day, month, and year are validated to be a real date (not in the future either) so I know that they are correct. They are entered as text fields by the user and I suppose I could make the `dateString` any format I want it that would be helpful.

```
let day = dayTextField.text
let month = monthTextField.text
let year = yearTextField.text
let dateString = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year)"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

let birthdate: NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) as NSDate
```

My problem is with the last line when I attempt to cast my date string to an NSDate, I get the following error:

```
'Date?' is not convertible to 'NSDate'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

I could force cast after "(from: `dateString`)" but I didn't think that would be the right thing to do.

Any help and insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Do not use `NSDate` in Swift. Use `Date`.

Comment: Why do you dare to use `NSDate` rather than `Date` ? I do not think _that would be the right thing to do_.

Comment: Hello! I was using it because I am using Parse server as my back end and here, https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#data-types, they use NSDate. I don't fully understand the advantage of using Date. Is that much better for some reason?

Comment: `Date` is the native Swift class (struct actually). `NSDate` is the old Objective-C class.

Comment: Have you noticed some sample code in Swift in that page uses `String` instead of `NSString` ? You use `Date` instead of `NSDate` in Swift code, when you want to use imported Parse APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is way easier for both you and the user if you let the user choose a date from a `UIDatePicker`. This has a lot of advantages:

- The user don't have to type in three text fields
- You can get the selected date via the `date` property. You don't need all these formatters and stuff
- You can set a maximum date that the user can select via the `maximumDate` property. This way you don't have to check if it is in the future manually. Just set `maximumDate` to now.
- The date picker will use different formats depending on the user's locale. You don't need to worry about it at all.

Just remember to set the `datePickerMode` to `.date`!

As for the conversion to `NSDate`, you can do this easily by this expression:

```
datePicker.date as NSDate
```

If you insist on using three text fields, you can do this:

```
dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) as NSDate? // note that this produces an optional
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use the UIDatePicker and if that doesn't work, resort to the "as NSDate?" solution.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine so check the valus in your textfield that are coming in ur variable or not

```
  let day = "10"
    let month = "12"
    let year = "2018"
    let dateString = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year)"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let birthdate: NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) as! NSDate
    print(birthdate)
```

but i would suggest you to use `Date` instead of `NSDate`.

Comment: Hello Mahesh and thanks for the reply. I really want it to be a NSDate. Why would I want to force cast it as you have? Is it acceptable to force cast a date as an NSDate?

Comment: @thalacker then it is also working code I have just tested it by assigning static dates and working fine and yes you can convert date to NSDate :)

Comment: Please don't use forced unwraps. Teaching people to force unwrap is gonna bite them later when the forced unwrap will start crashing the app.

Comment: @Cristik agree that's why I was suggesting to use Date instead of NSDate to avoid force wrapping

Comment: `NSDate` is not the cause of the forced unwrap here. You could write `as NSDate?`, there are no forced unwraps there.